# I cannot install pyHook

Tags: python, pyhook

I was trying to install `pyHook` with `pip` but its not working.

I went into `CMD` type `pip install pyHook`, but it says `could not find version`
I was using python 3.8, is there something I was missing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try it
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook
Then 
pip install [whatever].whl

Answer (score 1):

`pyHook` is not available for python 3. It is only available for python 2.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/pyhook/1.5.1/

The link attached above shows the list of python versions that are supported. `2.5`, `2.6` and `2.7`

Since you are using `3.8` which does not have a supported version you would get the following error.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhook
>   (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyhook

The alternatives are to find an alternative package that works for python 3.8 or to switch to python 2.7